# osclass how echo this sql?

Tags: sql, osclass

i want echo total of clcks of each product id stored in item_clicks sql.

```
ref_id    click
  1         15
  2         4
  3         12
```

I have used this sql call

$totalclicks = $conn->osc_dbFetchResults("SELECT click  FROM %st_item_click GROUP BY ref_id", DB_TABLE_PREFIX, osc_logged_user_id());

I get this echo

```
ID         Clicks
1            15
2            15
3            15
```

Comment: Can you really `SELECT click` without aggregation function? What DB server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks fine but it doesn't sound like the Osclass way to do it.

1. Try to take a look at [DAO in Osclass](https://doc.osclass.org/How_to_upgrade_your_plugins_to_new_DAO_classes).
2. Enable `OSC_DEBUG` and `OSC_DEBUG_DB` in your config.php to have the exact query that is being executed.

Also, take a minute or two to read the [plugin development page](https://doc.osclass.org/How_to_create_a_plugin) and this [tutorial that will get you through Osclass plugin development and the use of DAO](https://wearemadhouse.wordpress.com/2013/10/11/how-to-develop-osclass-plugins/).